# How can I fetch data from a JSON file with "complex" infos to datatables?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, datatables

I will show an example of the json I am trying to turn in a table with datatables and how I want it to look. I have tried everything and I'm new on this.

(if you want you can check the website, link yourself to the testing guild and try to see how it works to make a table like that in Reports)

What I would like to do:
I would like to get the datatable to be organized like that:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqx30.png)

Here goes some infos: there is boxLevel that goes from 0 to 5, 0 is meant to be stored at level 1 in table, 1 = lv2, lv3 = 4, lv4 = lv5 and 5 = 2 lv5

RcvTime is in Unix Epoch, would be cool to convert that in our date
Woudl appreciate if you could add the same as the printscreen there, to fetch monsters by single Date or period range.

Every level 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 has its own points value too, so in single date or period range it will show if people made the necessary points or not and the difference to accomplish that. (btw, the daily goal is 5 points a day)

JSON info are stored like this:

```
  "IGG_ID": 99999999,
  "guildDetail": "[TAG]Guild Name",
  "discardTime": 1600988400,
  "statInfo": {
    "helpSent": 2,
    "giftsCollectedTotal": 18,
    "giftsCollected": [
      0,
      16,
      2,
      0,
      0
    ]
  },
  "boxData": [
    {
      "SN": 3580,
      "Status": 1,
      "RcvTime": 1600902285,
      "BoxItemID": 2605,
      "PlayerName": "ACoolPlayerName",
      "isPurchase": false,
      "boxLevel": 0,
      "boxName": "[Incomum] Bônus da Ceifadora",
      "Item": {
        "ItemID": 1009,
        "Num": 2,
        "ItemRank": 0,
        "itemName": "30.000 de Comida"
      }
    },
    {
      "SN": 3581,
      "Status": 1,
      "RcvTime": 1600902348,
      "BoxItemID": 2756,
      "PlayerName": "AnotherName",
      "isPurchase": false,
      "boxLevel": 1,
      "boxName": "Espólio [Incomum] do Vodu Shaman",
      "Item": {
        "ItemID": 1258,
        "Num": 2,
        "ItemRank": 0,
        "itemName": "Acelerar pesquisa (10 m)"
      }
    },
```

**i would really appreciate if someone can help... thank you!**

Comment: It is not clear (at least, it is not clear to me) what the relationship is between your sample JSON and the screenshot you provided. DataTables works well when you can provide it with an array of arrays, or an array of objects (where those objects can have nested objects). Sub-arrays within objects may need to be flattened to be displayed easily. So, your `"boxData":...` looks straightforward, because it is an array of objects (with no nested arrays).

Comment: You mentioned that you "have tried everything" - why don't you [edit] your question, to show us something that is the closest to what you need - maybe that will help as a [mre].